# Riemann Sum look-alike

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, riemann-sum

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{n^4+k} \  sin\frac{2k\pi}{n}$$
I have found this Riemann Sum look-alike, but I have no idea how to approach it. Can you perhaps help me solve this?

The answer should be $-\frac{1}{4\pi} $.

Comment: Sounds like a discrete Fourier transform, if it was not for that $k$...